# Build a Map Using ROS Kinetic

Tags: navigation, mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How to setup Pioneer lx for building a map in ROS Kinetic..?

~Help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/260947/build-a-map-using-ros-kinetic/) by [Gaurav](https://answers.ros.org/users/30216/gaurav/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-05-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do the tutorials on the ROS wiki. There are many about that:

- http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_navigation/Tutorials/Build%20a%20map%20with%20SLAM
- http://wiki.ros.org/slam_gmapping/Tutorials/MappingFromLoggedData

or search here on ROS answers...

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2017-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1